# I want to write a each table object and its columns saperately without deleting the previous record

Tags: java, file

this is my class of table that includes Column that has Column name its data type and bool if its a primary key or not; and this list of columns combine to form one table.

I want to write this by calling a func public void SaveToFile(){} i have tried something as well but im confused how to write it by not deleting or changing the previous record(no Over writing); as i want a file of Database having each table object and its columns saperately by a line space.

you may take help from viewColumn(); func works correctly.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Table 
{
private ArrayList<Column> columns;
private String NAME;
private static int count=0;

public Table() 
{
    columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
    NAME=new String();

    this.NAME="Table"+count;
    count++;
}

public void AddColumn(Column column)
{

    columns.add(column);

}

public void SaveToFile() throws IOException
{
    File f=new File("Database.txt");
    f.createNewFile();
    BufferedReader b =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    ArrayList<Column> col =new ArrayList<Column>();
    String S =b.readLine();
   // *********************


    //*********************
}

public boolean DeleteColumn(String name)
{
    for (Column c : columns)
    {
        if (c.getname().equals(name)) {return columns.remove(c);}
    }
    return false;
}

public void viewColumns()
{
      System.out.append(NAME+"  ");

    for(Column c: columns)
  {
      System.out.append("\n");
      System.out.append(c.getname()+"  ");
      System.out.append((CharSequence) c.getdatatype()+"  ");

if(c.getPK()==true)
{
    System.out.print(true);
}     

  }
}

public String getNAME() {

    return NAME;
}

}
```

Comment: What has this got to do with 'makefile' ???

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to implement a "database" using a flat file.  This is not a good idea.  And one of the reasons that it is not a good idea is that it is difficult to update and delete records ... without rewriting the entire file.

I suggest that you use a real database (or SQLite) rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

---

> no i just want to create a file of a database... its a small project. i just want to keep record of how many tables are there in the Database and columns of each tables.

What you are implementing is a mini database that describes the Database.  But there are better ways to do this.

- Store the information in a new table in the real database.
- The information you are trying to store is already present in the real database and available via the JDBC metadata API.  Use that instead of replicating the metadata.

In addition to the problem of "reinventing the wheel" in your mini-database implementation, your current approach is creating a (redundant) 2nd description of the actual Database that has to (somehow) be kept in step with the real database's table structure metadata.

Comment: no i just want to create a file of a database... its a small project.  i just want to keep record of how many tables are there in the Database and columns of each tables.

Comment: it is my assignment !! to write tables  of a database on text file nothing else.. just help me out with writing text on a file, cursor movement,and giving spaces in entries.